# Inserting values into strings in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I am trying to iterate over some integer values  and insert them into an string which has to be in a weird format to work. The exact output (including the outer quotes) I need if the value was 64015 would be:

```
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
```

I have tried f string formatting but couldn't get it to work. It has problem with the backslashes and when I escaped them the output was not exactly like above string
Hopefully, I made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with `f-strings` and `.format()` but ultimately got this to work:

```
foo = 90210
bar = '"param={\\"zip\\":\\"%s\\"}"' % (foo)
print(bar)
```

giving:

```
"param={\"zip\":\"90210\"}"
```

Hopefully someone can give you an f-string alternative. I kept running into unallowed "\" in my f-string attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to escape the backslash and the double quotes seperately like this:

```
string = '"param={\\\"zip\\\":\\\"' + str(64015) + '\\\"}"'
```

The result of this is:

```
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternate ways to delimit the outer string (`'...'`, `'''...'''`, `"""..."""`) or use `str.format()` or old style `%`-formatting syntax to get there (see f-style workaround at the end):

```
s = s =  'param={"zip":"' + str(64015) + '"}' 
print(s)

s =  '''param={"zip":"''' + str(64015) +'''"}''' 
print(s)

s =  """param={"zip":"64015"}"""   # not suited for variable replacement 
print(s)

s =  'param={{"zip":"{0}"}}'.format(64015)
print(s)

s =  'param={"zip":"%s"}' % 64015
print(s)
```

Output:

```
param={"zip":"64015"}
param={"zip":"64015"}
param={"zip":"64015"}
param={"zip":"64015"}
```

If you need any `"\"` in there simply drop a `\\` in:

```
s =  '"param={\\"zip\\":\\"' + str(64015) + '\\"}"' 
print(s)

s =  '''"param={\\"zip\\":\\"''' + str(64015) +'''\\"}"''' 
print(s)


s =  '"param={{\\"zip\\":\\"{0}\\"}}"'.format(64015)
print(s)

s =  '"param={\\"zip\\":\\"%s\\"}"' % 64015
print(s)
```

Output:

```
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
```

The f-string workaround variant would look like so:

```
a = '\\"'
num = 64015
s = f'"param={{{a}zip{a}:{a}{num}{a}}}"'
```

and if printed also yields :

```
"param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
```

More on the topic can be found here: ['Custom string formatting' on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)

Comment: Well done on working out the f-string version.

Comment: @Patrick Artner Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Your answer with "\" is what I need but I don't want to print the answer. "s" will be an input to another function and its value (without being printed) has to be exactly "param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}". Just to give a bit of a context "s" will be assigned to "data" in the following function: r = requests.post(url , data= "param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}", headers)

Comment: @shora - in that case `a = '\\"'` + `s = f'"param={{{a}zip{a}:{a}{your_number}{a}}}"'` should work. If I were you I would do a quick test and try if `s = 'param={"zip":"64015"}'` is accepted by your api as well. Although otherwise documented it could/may work.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tested 'param={"zip":"64015"}'. Unfortunately, it doesn't work due to the way they design the API. That's why I have to go through the hassle of generating this string. Also, I have just check the value of s based on your updated string but it returns '"param={\\"zip\\":\\"your_number\\"}"' which still doesn't work because it has double backslashes instead of single. Seems that it is really hard to generate what I need!

Comment: @Shora   Then you do NOT need the \ before the " - if you debug something or use an IDE with inspect functionality on breaks it sometimes it escapes " for your viewing pleasure. Surest thing is to print() the string. Send if over once with, once without and see what works. You can change `a='"'` (single+double+single) to generate it without \

Comment: @PatrickArtner I played with the backslashes and the quotes but couldn't get it to work the way I want it. The only strange thing I can think of is to somehow assign print() output to a variable so I can use it as the input to the request but even have had no luck with that either yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only this?

```
a = "param={\"zip\":\"64015\"}"
b = a.split('=')
c = eval(b[1])
print(c)
print(c['zip'])
```

Result:

```
{'zip': '64015'}
64015
```

> Please note that evaluating (`eval()`) strings from unknown source may
> be dangerous! It may run the code that you are not expecting.